# make changes to html before append with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m calling a page using ajax and making changes to it using jquery

but the changes are not reflected after appending(append) it to a div

as the changes are done to the html but the html var remains the same.

how do i make the changes to the html var and then append to the DOM

if i use the code directly to the DOM then there will be changes in the previous elements in the DOM

the code

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'more_images.jsp',
data: ({uid:uid, aid:aid, imgid:imgid}) ,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{

    html = $.trim(html);
    $(html).filter('.corner-all').corner('5px');

    $(html).filter('ol.c_album > li .img_c').corner('3px');
    $(html).filter("ol.c_album > li ").find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
    $('#images_list').append(html);

}
});
```

thanks

Pradyut

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the DOM elements are created from the string and then modified by the further functions.  The changes are **not** made to the string.

Create a jQuery selection, cache it, modify it, then append it:

```
$images = $(html);
$images.filter('.corner-all').corner('5px');

$images.filter('ol.c_album > li .img_c').corner('3px');
$images.filter("ol.c_album > li ").find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
$('#images_list').append($images);
```

Comment: btw i want append to ol but modern browsers automatically closes ol... how can remove the last </ol> and then append into the DOM??

Comment: @Pradyut You mean you want to append the child elements of `$images` to `$('#images_list')`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
$('#images_list').append($(html)
  .filter('.corner-all').corner('5px').end()
  .filter('ol.c_album > li .img_c').corner('3px').end()
  .filter("ol.c_album > li ").find('a').attr('target', '_blank').end()
);
```

Comment: An extra `.end()` call is needed after the third `filter` call.

Comment: this code does not work for complex DOMs in the 'html' and the code will only append elements changed , not all the elements...

Comment: @Pradyut - ah sorry; you'd need to add another ".end()" in there - I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Pradyut - and yes, the code will work for "complex DOMs", and (with the change I just made) it will append all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reassign the variable html before appending it

```
...
html = $(html).filter('.corner-all').corner('5px');

html = $(html).filter('ol.c_album > li .img_c').corner('3px');
html = $(html).filter("ol.c_album > li ").find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

there something wrong in your code.
as i understood, your ajax-request returns html-code that you append to #images_list element
the html param of success function contains that html code. 
$(html).filter('.corner-all').corner('5px');
does not make sense. you trying to access to html selector.

Comment: `html` is a variable in this case - the response of the `$.ajax` call